# Getting generic list as serialsed property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i get the serialised property of List modifiers? In the property drawer script List ListOfNumbers and int[] ArrayOfNumbers are perfectly accessible but the modifier list is always null.

```
    [Serializable]
public class Modifloat
{
    [SerializeField] float baseValue;
    [SerializeField] List<IMod> modifiers;

    [SerializeField] List<int> ListOfNumbers;
    [SerializeField] int[] ArrayOfNumbers;

    float currentValue;

    public float Value { get => currentValue; }

     public Modifloat(float baseValue)
    {
        ListOfNumbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        ArrayOfNumbers = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        modifiers = new List<IMod>() { new Modifier(3, 3) };
        this.baseValue = baseValue;
        TymerEngine.Engine.InitialiseMe(this);
    }
    public void AddModifier(IMod modifier)
    {
        modifiers.Add(modifier);
    }
}


[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Modifloat))]
public class ModifloatEditor : PropertyDrawer

{

    int rowHeight = 20;

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty prop, GUIContent label)
    {
        
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            var amount3 = prop.FindPropertyRelative("ArrayOfNumbers").arraySize;
            var amount2 = prop.FindPropertyRelative("ListOfNumbers").arraySize;
            var baseV = prop.FindPropertyRelative("baseValue");
            var modifiersList = prop.FindPropertyRelative("modifiers");
            var amount = prop.FindPropertyRelative("modifiers").arraySize;
            return (amount * rowHeight) + rowHeight;
        }
        else
            return rowHeight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I don't know a good answer tbh but at least can tell you it won't work that way.

If the field is not serialized then the editor can not find it. As a little "preview" which fields are serialized simply comment out your editor scripts .. if it doesn't appear in the Inspector that way then it also won't be available for your editor script ;)

See [Script Serialization -> Serialization Rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

> **Simple field types that can be serialized**
>
> - Custom non-abstract, non-generic classes with the Serializable attribute (See How to ensure a custom class can be serialized, below.)
> - Custom structs with the Serializable attribute References to objects that derive from UnityEngine.Object
> - Primitive data types (int, float, double, bool, string, etc.)
> - Enum types Certain Unity built-in types: Vector2, Vector3, Vector4, Rect, Quaternion, Matrix4x4, Color, Color32, LayerMask,
>   AnimationCurve, Gradient, RectOffset, GUIStyle

**Interfaces are not part of it!**

The only reason why e.g. `List<int>` is serialized is because unity has a special built-in Serialization support for `List<T>` and `T[]` as long as `T` fulfills the afore mentioned rules.

---

Now **assuming the implementations of your interface derive from `UnityEngine.Object`** (such as e.g. Components or ScriptableObject) then (and only then) you **could** use [`[SerializeReference]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html).

**BUT** afaik unfortunately it doesn't work on a `List<T>` but rather only single fields since as said for lists Unity has a particular serialization.

---

So for now the only option I see would be instead of an interface rather have a base class implemting the interface. **Still assuming you have different `IMod` `ScriptableObjects` or `MonoBehaviour`** you could do e.g.

```
public abstract BaseMod : ScriptableObject : IMod
{
    // public abstract WhateverHasToBeImplemented;
}
```

and then

```
public class SpecificMod : BaseMod
{
    // public override WhateverHasToBeImplemented;
}
```

and use in your field

```
public List<BaseMod> modifiers;
```